# Examples of ‘temporary canvas’

Tags: tabs, templates

[image]I have this app.
I have a default white canvas where i'm abble to draw something that is always temporary.
If the I decide that I want to keep what I've done I must click 'keep' and it creates a tab with my drawing.
I would like to see some examples of how to tell the user that what is being drawn is always temporary till he asks the app to save it.

Do you know any examples os temporary sheets? (I tried overlays and dropshadows but I want to see other ways of making my message clear).

Thank you

Comment: Hi Ana, can you provide a mockup or wireframe explaining this flow? Right now it sounds really broad

Comment: Where the "keep" button is? Nearby may be a candidate location.

Answer (score 1):

**Let user focus on drawing process, don't make her think on saving, and don't set her in fear of loosing results.** It's more user-friendly approach, and many apps follow it.

**Example 1:** Pressing `Ctrl` + `S` was my primary task while editing an important document in MS Word. And the totally different experience with Google Docs. Just work with content, and the app does the rest.

You never sure if user wants to save or to discard the drawing, but the pain of loosing is too high. And this can be crucial for your product!

I propose to invert the approach: **let user discards the canvas, if she doesn't need it**, rather than to save the canvas if she needs it.

**Example 2:** Xara Designer does it perfectly: *Untitled1** and *Untitled2** tabs contain unsaved drawings, still these are auto-saved. When I close the tab  it asks me whether I want to Save it or to Discard it.

[image]